# Modify a refinery CMS extension after it is generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, refinerycms

I followed the [tutorial to generate an extension for refinery CMS](http://www.refinerycms.com/edge-guides/generate-an-extension-to-use-your-mvcs).

I am required to modify this extension: new name, new fields, remove some old fields..etc..

Is this feasible with refinery CMS or I will have to create a new extension from scratch to replace the one I have?